# How to interpret CDC::DrawText returning negative value?

Tags: c++, printing, mfc

I am debugging some code that uses the MFC CDC Class for printing documents, and which have issues with the preview-printing for determining the total number of pages.

When comparing return values from `CDC::DrawText` for certain elements, I notice that when drawing to memory the return value is positive but then when drawing to printer the return value is negative.

The CDC documentations says `DrawText` return "*The height of the text if the function is successful.*"
What does a negative value mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that your two CDC's (memory and printer) have been placed in different [mapping modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=vs-2019#setmapmode).

For example, when the CDC's underlying device context is in `MM_TEXT` mode, then positive `y` is *down* whereas, in (most) other modes, positive 'y' is up. A quick test on my own system (albeit using a screen-based CDC) has shown that `CDC::DrawText()` returns a *positive* value when the DC is in `MM_TEXT` mode but a *negative* value for (e.g.) `MM_ISOTROPIC` or `MM_HIMETRIC`.

Whether or not you have explicitly changed the mapping mode for either of your CDCs, I don't know! But, even if you haven't, the MFC framework has probably "done something" to the printer device context - either before you've retrieved it or (more likely) in the `OnPreparePrinting` function.

Comment: This (and your comment) brought me on the right track to solve it.
The printer-CDC had been set to "MM_LOMETRIC", but the memory-CDC had the mode "MM_TEXT". The memory-CDC was created with CreateCompatibleDC(&printer-CDC), but apparently that does not set it to the same mapping mode.